# C# Win form Selenium hanging

Tags: c#, selenium-chromedriver

I have a c# Win form app that uses Selenium/ChromeWebDriver. I have used Selenium in a Win form app on many occasions over the last 10 years. However, recently I have encountered the following issue. App hangs/freezes after executing  the code (shown below)

This fires up the Chrome browser displays the required web page. The app then displays the Win form. However, debugging the code does not hit the catch clause or any code after the try/catch clause. At this point the app is frozen - the Win form does not respond, VS debug functions (step into etc...) are not available. The only solution is to quit VS execution. As I said, I have used Selenium many times with no issues. Any ideas appreciated. Environment, VS 2019 Preview (and tried with VS 2017), Selenium WebDriver (v4.0.30319 (tried latest pre-releases also))

```
try
{          
    seleniumDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl(mainURL);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Try Catch");
}
```

OUTPUT PANE(doesn't seem to show anything significant:-
'DividendExtractor.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WinTypes.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'DividendExtractor.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WinTypes.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'DividendExtractor.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WinTypes.dll'
The thread 0x6940 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x4f40 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x3f58 has exited with code 0 (0x0).

STACKTRACE:-
    [External Code]

> DividendExtractor.exe!DividendExtractor.Form1.ExtractAllData() Line 41  C#
>       DividendExtractor.exe!DividendExtractor.Form1.BtnExtractDividendInfo_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e) Line 34   C#
>       [External Code] 
>       DividendExtractor.exe!DividendExtractor.Program.Main() Line 19  C#
>       [External Code] 
>       System.Windows.Forms.ni.dll![Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, native debugger attempting to walk managed call stack]   Unknown

UPDATE: AFTER MANY YEARS OF USING IT I EVENTUALLY GAVE UP ON SELENIUM. I STARTED USING ANGLESHARP. NOT SURE IF ANGLESHARP IS AS RICH A TOOL AS SELENIUM BUT SO FAR IT IS SERVING MY PURPOSES.

Comment: What do you get to see in the output pane of VS?

Comment: Use the debugger to see what is going on.  Enable unmanaged debugging, enable the symbol server and use Debug > Break All when it hangs.  Copy/paste the stack trace of the main thread into your question.